# linking a css file to my html file

Tags: html, css

I am having way too much trouble figuring out how to link a .css file to my .html file. They are both in the same folder on my desktop.

I created the these in sublime and when I made the styles.css I did saveas selected the folder on my desktop that my html was in and then saved it as a css file. Something that might be the problem is when I look at the files in the folder, the html say filename.html but the css just says style without the .css and the file type is file. I tried to go into the properties and change it to .css but that also didn't work.

This is the html file
I have tried "/style.css" , "foldername/style.css" , and the entire path

```
<html>


<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<body>

<div class ="test">
    test
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the css file with the file name of style.css

```
.test{color:green; margin:50px;}
```

Comment: *Something that might be the problem is when I look at the files in the folder, the html say filename.html but the css just says style without the .css and the file type is file.* — This makes me suspect that you are using Windows Explorer to examine the file names and may have it configured to hide file names of recognised file types. That is a good way to confuse yourself, so tracking down that setting and making sure it is off would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you quentin, but I already checked that. I found a solution to my problem although I don't understand how it solved it. Exactly what happened was I click on the css file to open it and it said open with and I forgot I had installed something called brackets for html coding and opened it with that and I think that converted it into a css file, while I guess originally it wasn't one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the "link" tag is inside the "html" tag. Try to put it outside any tags.

Answer (score -2):

Did you name your CSS file "styles.css" or "style.css?"

When working locally, make your css paths relative. So it would look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">
```

Comment: it is style.css and I don't understand what making my file paths relative means. I did save as, put it in the same folder on the desktop as the html and underneath where you put the filetype, I clicked on css

Comment: The question says that the two files are in the same folder. It does not say that the CSS file is in the parent directory of the directory containing the HTML file.

Comment: @Justin — Relative means "not using an absolute URL" which would be one starting with a scheme (such as `http:`) and then including everything including the server. You're already doing that.